# Wordpress Inline Style missing

Tags: customization, css

I created a wordpress site and added some inline styles.  They show up on the page in the section:

```
<style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">
    /*
    Welcome to Custom CSS!

    To learn how this works, see http://wp.me/PEmnE-Bt
    */
.... Style stuff...
```

On the admin page I used to be able to click on a link to edit the inline style.  The link no longer lets me edit the inline style and I can't manage or remove it.  Instead it opens up a theme editor where I can edit different pages of the website.

Is there a way to access the inline styles or how can I remove them?

Thanks

Comment: It was stored in the database. After several searches on the web I figured it out. Data was stored in posts table in the post_content field. Deleting the data fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends where you added the inline style. If you added it into a theme file, like header.php for example, then you should be able to locate it at Appearance->Editor.

If instead the code was added via a plugin or from a page`s admin editor or something similar, then you need to track the page and see if the code is where it should be.

Comment: I know it's stored in the database somewhere so I thought there was a default plugin that sets it.  Now instead of editing the css it edits the theme.  I'm not sure what plugin I used.  It would be nice if you could see all the inline css thats stored in the db and edit it.  Guess I have to search the DB for the CSS...

Comment: Do you know where I might find the custom inline css.  I think it's in the DB but not sure.

Comment: Do you think you could share with me a link to your website so I can take a look at?